# PHP if() does not return true nor calls all elements

Tags: php

I have following part of code:

```
if (($product->uploadable_files != $files_count || $product->text_fields != $text_count) && !count($this->errors) && !$product->update())
        $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('An error occurred while updating the custom configuration.');
```

How come (I'm completly lost atm) it does not call `Tools::displayError` nor `$product->update()`

At last one of those, should be called. And it is not.

Comment: Can you print every value you are testing?

Comment: Change `!count($this->errors)` to `count($this->errors) > 0`. `!0 -> true` && `!1 -> false`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This probably means it doesn't even reach that point. You can group the if-statement in three groups:

1st: `$product->uploadable_files != $files_count || $product->text_fields != $text_count`

2nd: `!count($this->errors)`

3rd: `!$product->update()`

If one of those groups is false, the entire condition will be false. And if 1st is false, it doesn't even reach 2nd and 3rd. And if 2nd is false, it doesn't reach 3rd.

Also, [`count`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) never returns false. You're probably checking whether `$this->errors` is empty, so just use `empty($this->errors)`.

Comment: Right.. My bad. I was thinking it should behave like `||` and *should* check all conditions. I mistook && and ||.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on treegarden's answer, 
`count()` can evaluate to true if its handled incorrectly.

```
var_dump(count([]));            # 0
var_dump(count([]) == false);   # true
var_dump(count([]) === false);  # false
```

Count returns the number of elements in in the first parameter. If the parameter is **not** an array or object *with* implemented Countable interface, *1 will be returned*. There is one exception, if array_or_countable is NULL, 0 will be returned.

Instead use `empty()`:

```
var_dump(!empty([])); # false
```

Comment: it still don't return ``false`` how he said^^

Comment: Yes you're right, though it still doesn't return `false`, and checking for !0 is definitely bad practice.

Comment: This is common practice in Prestashop. I did not write this code. It's from 1.6.1.0.
Also, `count()` returns *Integer* type, not boolean. So `===` is not adequate here and will never be true unless you cast it to boolean.

Comment: I know it returns an integer type. I only mentioned it can return false depending on evaluation, didn't say boolean type :). And as treegarden said (and I concur) using count over empty (in this example) is a bad practice, and slower in execution too.

Answer (score -1):

&& checks if both are true. If first one is false, it ends there, doesnt go anywhere else, it is a short-circuit as manual says. Same goes for ||.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

```
// --------------------
// foo() will never get called as those operators are short-circuit

$a = (false && foo());
$b = (true  || foo());
$c = (false and foo());
$d = (true  or  foo());

// --------------------
// "||" has a greater precedence than "or"

// The result of the expression (false || true) is assigned to $e
// Acts like: ($e = (false || true))
$e = false || true;

// The constant false is assigned to $f and then true is ignored
// Acts like: (($f = false) or true)
$f = false or true;

var_dump($e, $f);

// --------------------
// "&&" has a greater precedence than "and"

// The result of the expression (true && false) is assigned to $g
// Acts like: ($g = (true && false))
$g = true && false;

// The constant true is assigned to $h and then false is ignored
// Acts like: (($h = true) and false)
$h = true and false;

var_dump($g, $h);
?>
```